# How to get the length of char array without displaying it multiple times

Tags: java

How do I keep them separate so, that it doesn't display multiple times based on the length of char? Aside from for loop what other methods I can use to achieve the output I need. Here's the code:

```
for(i=0;i <= s.length; i++){
    int fc = s.length;

    if(fc == 1){
        System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*");
    }
    if(fc == 2 || fc == 4){
        System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*b+");
    }
    if(fc >= 5 ){
        System.out.println("String accepted under rule abb");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

I mean how do I make it just only one "String accepted under rule `a*b+`" instead displaying it according to the length of array.

Comment: If you don't want to display it, then don't display it.

Comment: Weird spacing .

Comment: Just remove the loop. You should use else if statements too.

Comment: I need the length of char so that, I can compare it to the if conditions.

Comment: @bryonkurtsegunto _I need the length of char so that, I can compare it to the if conditions_ you don't need a `for loop` to get the length of the `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a loop if nothing in your code change at each iteration of the code?

```
   int fc = s.length;


   if(fc == 1){
       System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*");
   }
   if(fc == 2 || fc == 4){
       System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*b+");
   }
   if(fc >= 5 ){
        System.out.println("String accepted under rule abb");
   }
```

or add a `break` statement to terminate the loop inside each `if`

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the loop and just use `if-else` statements

```
int fc = s.length;

if(fc == 1) {
   System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*");
}
else
if(fc == 2 || fc == 4) {
   System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*b+");
}
else
if(fc >= 5 ) {
   System.out.println("String accepted under rule abb");
}
```

**OR**

add `break` statement inside each `if statement`

```
for(i=0;i <= s.length; i++) {

     int fc = s.length;

     //make sure that fc is not equal to 0 to avoid infinite loop
     if(fc == 0) { 
        break;
     }

     if(fc == 1) {
         System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*");
         break;
     }
     if(fc == 2 || fc == 4) {
         System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*b+");
         break;
     }
     if(fc >= 5 ) {
         System.out.println("String accepted under rule abb");
         break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int fc = s.length;
if(fc == 1){
    System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*");
}
if(fc == 2 || fc == 4){
    System.out.println("String accepted under rule a*b+");
}
if(fc >= 5 ){
    System.out.println("String accepted under rule abb");
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why your code answers the question.